# Facebook "Mobile Web" Settings

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, oauth, web

I'm using Scribe API (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) to authenticate via OAuth.

I've figured out 2 issues:

First I've called OAUTH dialog with "display=touch" and it was working like a charm, but the final step weren't redirecting via 302, It was showing a javascript code with "window.location.href=REDIRECT_URL" in my webview.

My problem is that I have changed "how your app integrates with Facebook" from "Website" to "Mobile Web".

Now I'm getting an error:

"API Errror Code: 191"

"The specified URL is not owned by the application"

"Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application Configuration"

Can anyone help me please?

these are my settings:

App type: web

sandbox mode: enabled

Remove Deprecated APIs: enabled

Stream post URL security: enabled

Upgrade to Requests 2.0: enabled

Require manage_notifications: enabled

Forces use of login secret for OAuth call and for auth.login: disabled

Encrypted Access Token: enabled

Requests 2.0 Efficient: disabled

Enhanced Auth Dialog: disabled

Graph Batch API Exception Format: disabled

**App Domain: I fill and try to save the information but when I reopen the data is not filled**

Summary:

When "Website" without display option, at the final step I receive a 302 response.

When "Website" with "display=touch" the webview receives a script "window.location.href" instead of a 302 redirect response (the OAuth dialog was in a Android Webview).

When I've changed from "Website" to "Mobile Web" I couldn't access the facebook Oauth dialog: API Errror Code: 191
The specified URL is not owned by the application. But the URL wasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just Enable "Requests 2.0 Efficient" at Advanced Settings and "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" (website)